# Is this series of hermite polynomials $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{2^n n!}} H_n(x)$ a known function?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is this series of hermite polynomials $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{2^n n!}} H_n(x)$ a known function?

Thank you!